# jQuery: html(data) not clearing existing elements

Tags: jquery

I've three `div` elements as follows

```
<div id='branch-1'>
   <ul>
     <li><span>Parent-1</span></li>
     <li><span>Parent-2</span></li>
     <li><span>Parent-3</span></li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div id='branch-2'></div>
<div id='branch-3'></div>
```

First `div` elements will be loaded with page,if user clicks on `Parent-1` then its child's are loading in second `div`,similarly for `Parent-2 and Parent-3`, using `ajax` as follows.

```
$("div#branch-1 ul li span").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'html',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $("div#branch-2").html(data);
            $("div#branch-3").empty();
        }
    });
});
```

Again if user clicks on second `div` elements then I'm loading its child elements in third `div` using `ajax` as follows

```
$(document).on("click", "div#branch-2 ul li span"function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'html',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $("div#branch-3").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

**Actual Question:** Sometimes `$("div#branch-3").html(data);` is not clearing existing data,for that reason I've tried following statements before `$("div#branch-3").html(data);`

```
 $("div#branch-3").html(""); // Not worked
 //OR
 $("div#branch-3").empty(); // Not worked
 //OR
 $("div#branch-3").contents().remove(); // Not worked
```

If I change above `selector` from `div#branch-3` to `div#branch-3 ul` or `div#branch-3 li` or `div#branch-3 span` then all above statements are working fine,

1. Why `html(data)` is not able to replace existing data ?
2. After changing `selector` why its clearing the existing elements though I'm passing `parent element id` as `selector`

**Added Additional Info:** As I said above **sometimes** `.html(data)` is not clearing the existing data, following is the case

Suppose for `Parent-1` have two child's lets say `Child-1,Child-2`,again `Child-1` have two Child's `A,B` and `Child-2` have three child's `X,Y,Z`.Think if user clicks on `Child-2` then `X,Y,Z` are showing in `branch-3 div` its fine, again if user clicks on `Child-1` then `X,Y` are replacing with `A,B` but `Z` is still exist. If I try to point its(Z) location in firebug then its disappearing.

Comment: You mean it's merging the new data with the old contents, instead of replacing it? Or it's not changing the data at all?

Comment: I have never experimented behaviour like this, and I am using plenty of .html() and .empty() in my web app. Are you sure that your callbacks are well called? Have you tried to create a debug breakpoint using console (F12)?

Comment: @Barmar: Suppose I've two child's(Child-1,Child-2) for Parent-1,again Child-1 have two Child's(A,B) and Child-2 have three child's(X,Y,Z).Think if user clicks on Child-2 then `X,Y,Z` are showing in `branch-3` div its fine, again if user clicks on Child-1 then X,Y are replacing with A,B but Z is still exist. If try point its(Z) location in firebug then its disappearing.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding that explanation. Could you show the actual results in the question?

Comment: @Barmar: Once check I've updated the question

Comment: That's the same thing you wrote in your comment, it doesn't clarify it at all. Please post the HTML you expect to get and the HTML you're getting instead. Real HTML, not just descriptions X, Y, Z.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
$("div#branch-3").html(markUp).trigger("create");
```

Comment: Any how I'm able to get what I want, but I want know the reason for its peculiar behavior

Comment: checked in `chorme and FF`

Comment: seems to me like a version issue with jQuery or browser

Answer (score 0):

Actually as I think, your problem is that - `success` function is not called. To check is this right idea add alert("I'm in!") to you your success:

```
    success: function (data) {
        alert("I'm in!");
        $("div#branch-3").html(data);
    }
```

Comment: Its not problem with `ajax` call I've checked how you have suggested, I'm getting data from `ajax` call.

Comment: alert("I'm in!") is getting called?